# When is this a group?

Tags: group-theory

I've been trying to study group theory on my own, and came across the following question:

Given a set defined by objects of the form $\lbrace a^i \otimes b^j\rbrace$ for integers $i,j$, such that the identity element is $1=a^0=b^0$.  Additionally, there are some integers $m,n\geq 2$ such that $a^m=b^n=1$ but for all integers $1\leq k<m, a^k\neq1$ and for all integers $1\leq k<n, b^k\neq1$.  Additionally, the following properties hold:
$$(a^x\otimes1)\otimes(a^y\otimes B)=a^{x+y}\otimes B$$
$$(A\otimes b^x)\otimes (1\otimes b^y)= A\otimes b^{x+y}$$

For each of the following definitions for $b\otimes a$, for what values of $m,n$ does this constitute a group, and what group is it isomorphic to (in the simplest expression of that group):

1. $b\otimes a=a\otimes b$
2. $b\otimes a=a^{-1}\otimes b$
3. $b\otimes a=a\otimes b^{-1}$
4. $b\otimes a=a^{-1}\otimes b^{-1}$

My attempt:

All of these sets are closed and contain the identity operator.  What remains to define this as a group is to check that the operator is well defined and associative.

1. This operator is always well defined and associative, and so this is always a group.  If $gcd(m,n)=1$, this group is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_{mn}$.  Otherwise, it is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_m\times C_n$
2. If $m=2$, this definition is identical to that in 1).  If $m>2, n=2$, this defines the dihedral group $D_m$.  Otherwise, from a sampling of values of $m,n$ that I tried, it appears that this is not well defined and associative.
3. If $n=2$, this definition is identical to that in 1).  If $m=2,n>2$, this defines the dihedral group $D_n$.  Otherwise, from a sampling of values of $m,n$ that I tried, it appears that this is not well defined and associative.
4. If $m=2$ or $n=2$, this relationship is identical to at least one of the previous three.  From a sampling of values of $m,n>2$, it appears that this operator is not well defined and associative.

My questions:

A) Did I miss any groups that are defined by one of the above relationships?  Did I correctly identify the dihedral and cyclic groups (and the direct product of cyclic groups)?

B) How do I more rigorously prove that for $m,n>2$, relationships 2-4 have no groups?

EDIT: I forgot to prove inversibility.
The inverses of $a^i\otimes b^j$ are:

1. $a^{-i}\otimes b^{-j}$
2. $a^i\otimes b^{-j}$ if $j\neq0$ and $a^{-i}$ if $j=0$
3. $a^{-i}\otimes b^j$ if $i\neq0$ and $b^{-j}$ if $i=0$
4. $a^i\otimes b^j$ if $ij\neq0$ and $a^{-i}\otimes b^{-j}$ if $ij=0$

EDIT 2:
A proof that for $m>2$, 2) cannot be a group if $n$ is odd.  Assume that out operator is well-defined and associative. First, by iterating the relationship of 2), we can expand the relationship to show that $b\otimes a^i=a^{-i}\otimes b$.  Next, we show: $$a=1\otimes a= b^n\otimes a= b^{n-1}\otimes a^{-1}\otimes b = b^{n-2}\otimes a^{(-1)^2}\otimes b^2=...=a^{(-1)^n}\otimes b^n= a^{(-1)^n}\otimes1=a^{(-1)^n}=a^{-1}$$

This would prove that $a$ is its own inverse, which is a contradiction of our assumptions.

A similar proof can be applied to show that 3) has no groups for $n>2$ and $m$ odd, and that 4) has no groups for $m,n>2$ and either of $m,n$ odd